# Azure Mobile App and navigation properties

Tags: azure-mobile-services

I'm using an Azure Mobile App for a Xamarin Forms application and wondering if it is possible load navigation properties of an entity when getting it from the db?

Here is a code example:
"var menuItems = await client.GetTable'<'MenuItem'>'().ReadAsync();"

menuItem has a navigation property called comments. In postman I can load these by adding a parameter of $expand=comments on the end of my query string, I'm stuck on how to add this to the code in my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer #1:  Use an [ExpandProperty] to automatically set $expand on the query.  See chapter 3 of the Zumo Book at http://aka.ms/zumobook

Answer #2: You don't want to do this (HONEST!)  It destroys any data normalization that you are trying to do.

Comment: Before you answered I was able to add $extend to my request using a DelegatingHandler on the client side, but through reading your book I'm seeing what you mean with Answer #2. Great book by the way, I was up reading till 3am.